# Images are not showing up over https

Tags: image, https, web

I am facing a real weird issue with my images over HTTPS.

I can see the image with HTTP in the URL but as soon as I change it to HTTPS, it starts showing 404 for the image.

Please advice as this one is becoming a real pain for me.

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: Is your server configured to serve up content over HTTPS? Does it have an SSL certificate configured?

Comment: I am sure that the configurations are up to the mark as few of the images are getting showed up